# JQuery Validation - Fields are not getting unhighlited

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a very basic form with Jquery validations in it.

**Requirement:** If name fields are not empty, address is required otherwise not.

This works fine, the only issue is that the red highlight never goes away, even when the fields become valid.

To reproduce:

1. Add some text to `First Name`, and hit `Save` button.

   > **Expected result:** All the required fields will be highlighted with error text.
2. Remove text from `First Name`, and hit `Save` button

   > **Expected result:** Highlight and error text should go away.
   > **Actual result:** Error text goes away, but highlight wont.

Is there a fix for this issue?

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {

    isNullOrWhitespace = function(input) {
      return !input || !input.trim();
    };

    isNameEmpty = function() {

      var name = $("#FirstName").val() + $("#LastName").val();
      return isNullOrWhitespace(name);
    };

    $("#application").validate({
      rules: {
        FirstName: {
          required: function() {
            return !isNameEmpty();
          }
        },
        LastName: {
          required: function() {
            return !isNameEmpty();
          }
        },
        Address1: {
          required: function() {
            return !isNameEmpty();
          }
        },
        City: {
          required: function() {
            return !isNameEmpty();
          }
        },
        Zip: {
          required: function() {
            return !isNameEmpty();
          }
        },
        SomeOtherField: {
        required: true
        },
      },
      highlight: function(input) {
        $(input).addClass("error");
      },
      unhighlight: function(input) {
        $(input).removeClass("error");
      },
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert("Submitted");
      }
    });

  });
```

```css
label.error {
    color: #dc3545 !important;
}
input.error {
    border: 1px solid #dc3545 !important;
}
input.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #dc3545 !important;
}
select.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #dc3545 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/additional-methods.min.js"></script>


<form id="application">
  <div>
    <input class="form-control name-part" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" placeholder="First" type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="form-control name-part" id="LastName" name="LastName" placeholder="Last" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="form-control" id="Address1" name="Address1" placeholder="Address Line 1" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="form-control" id="Address2" name="Address2" placeholder="Address Line 2" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="form-control" id="City" name="City" placeholder="City" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="form-control" id="Zip" name="Zip" placeholder="Zip" type="text" value="">
  </div>
    <div>
    <input class="form-control" id="SomeOtherField" name="SomeOtherField" placeholder="Some Other Required Field" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="bnSaveApplication" type="submit">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I think your usage of the plugin is completely wrong.  Normal expected usage is with `required: true`, which means the field is always required - then the plugin evaluates whether the `required` rule is satisfied or not.  You are actually constantly toggling the `required` rule on/off with your custom `isNameEmpty()` function.  The actual rules should not toggle on/off as the user is typing in the fields.   Just put `required: true` and see if it behaves the same.

Comment: *"the only issue is that the red highlight never goes away, even when the fields become valid."* Valid?  When you trigger an error and then wipe out the contents of a required field, the field is invalid... as least that's the normal default behavior.

Comment: @Sparky: What you are talking about is `dependency-expression` overload of the `required` method, there is another overload for providing a `dependency-callback`. You might want to look at their documentation again with examples of the `required` method with a function callback. https://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/

Comment: @Sparky: If the field stays invalid on wiping out the contents, even the error message should have persisted, not just the highlight. Also, I am more concerned that the fields are not being clear from error highlight on form submit, where the entire form is validated on submit.

Comment: As a contributor, I am very familiar with the documentation.  There is nothing wrong with using an expression or function to dynamically toggle a rule on/off.  However, a rule is normally toggled off when a rule is no longer needed at all, not when a rule is simply satisfied.  In other words, if you want to evaluate whitespace, empty, or trim, then do it with a custom method/rule instead of toggling the evaluation function itself.

Comment: @Sparky: In my mind, it is still similar to checking/unchecking a checkbox and making an input required/not required. In this case, instead of checkbox, an input having or not having text serves as the check for other controls. I might be not thinking it through or missing something, so the plugin is not working unexpectedly. Also, I agree with you that setting up custom a rule is another way to handle this.

Comment: It's potentially problematic when the toggle trigger is the content of the field itself rather than an external control.  You're really much better off with a custom method, where the plugin itself is properly handling the event triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I am currently solving it. I still feel this is a hack, but till I can find a good resolution, I am stuck with this.

1. Added a custom class to all the controls that needs to be treated as group.
2. During `unhighlight`, remove the error class from the all elements decorated with this custom class. Also, remove `label` elements for error messages.

   ```
       unhighlight: function (input) {
               $(input).removeClass("error");

               if (isNameEmpty()) {
                 $(".custom-class").removeClass("error");
                 $(".custom-class").siblings("label").remove();
               }
           }
   ```

**Caution**: This solution needs to be used carefully. Errors are removed here based on just one condition, because that's the only validation my controls need. But if there are multiple validations on a single control (e.g. min, max, etc.) along with `required`, using this code will remove all the errors.